# When the kids were getting attacked couldn’t they just leave the game?

Tags: plot-explanation, ready-player-one

In Ready Player One there were multiple times when the “high five” were under attack by forces, sometimes being under some seriously heavy fire.

Instead of fighting back and shooting why couldn’t they just touch their head and leave the game?

Then their avatar would be saved and nothing would happen.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the book on which the movie is based, it says:

> Logging out of your OASIS account while you were engaged in combat was
>   the same thing as committing suicide.  During the log-out sequence,
>   your avatar froze in place for sixty seconds, during which time you
>   were totally defenseless and susceptible to attack.  The log-out
>   sequence was designed this way to prevent avatars from using it as an
>   easy way to escape a fight.  You had to stand your ground or retreat
>   to a safe location before you could log out.

I assume that the immediate log out shown in the movie was only available if you weren't engaged in PVP combat.